# Android: Draw line behind ImageView in list item

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

I would like to draw a line behind an ImageView in a list item which fills the entire height of the list item. The image in the following link shows my desired result. The blue line is the one I want.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbdsuvcyxaz1pnj/listViewDesired.png?dl=0

I have a ListView with a custom adapter and layout for each row. The row is comprised of a relative layout with a few elements: an image with a specific size anchored to the left, a text view with a specific size anchored to the right, and a text view which fills the rest of the space in between.

I want to show a thin line coming out of the top and bottom of the ImageView and fill the rest of the space for that list item. The List item's size can become larger than the image size if there is a lot of text in the middle. How can I achieve this?

I have tried multiple approaches with a framelayout with a view that matches/fills the parent and the ImageView, and a linearlayout with 3 views (top line, imageView, bottom line that fills the parent), and the image looks correct in the IDE render, but the lines do not extend all the way or even show up when the app is actually running.

This is my layout without a line behind the imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:padding="@dimen/marginTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <!--Line should be "behind" (extending from top and bottom) of this imageView and should extend to the full height of the RelativeLayout after it has been rendered-->
  <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
          android:src="@drawable/face"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/catchSize"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/catchSize"/>
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tabUpdateTime"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tabText"
          android:text="@string/long_string"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tabIcon"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tabUpdateTime"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show some UI or image that what exactly you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 10 reputation so I can't upload image. Stupid SO!

Comment: *Stupid SO* so you are asking help on stupid things. if you've enough knowledge so you can upload image somewhere else and can pass link here.

Comment: I have linked the image I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the issue by using an enclosing LinearLayout instead. I have changed some of the margin stuff but I get my desired effect. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/marginTop"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/marginTop"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!--Line should be "behind" (extending from top and bottom) of this imageView and should extend to the full height of the RelativeLayout after it has been rendered-->
  <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:clipChildren="false"
          android:id="@+id/frameTabIcon"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
            android:id="@+id/tabTopLine"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/lineThickNess"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTop"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ImageView
            android:onClick="deletePersonOnClick"
            android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/face"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/catchSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/catchSize"/>

    <View
          android:id="@+id/tabBottomLine"
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:minHeight="@dimen/marginTop"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/lineThickNess"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginTop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabUpdateTime"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabText"
            android:text="@string/long_string"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tabUpdateTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create separate layout for Image as well as Vertical Line and to draw Vertical Line you need to add a View with width of 1dp or the thickness you want.

Try with the following Code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- Line should be "behind" (extending from top and bottom) of this imageView and should extend to the full height of the RelativeLayout after it has been rendered -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tabText" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/verticleLine"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/catchSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/catchSize"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:src="@drawable/face" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabUpdateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tabUpdateTime"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:text="@string/long_string" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. The images were shrunk a lot and all of the text was bunched together. The line did however go through the images.

Comment: for that you need to give fix size according to screen resolution and padding too.